# Access local file in cloud environment

Tags: java, file, azure

I'm trying to access GeoLiteCity File, it's working on my local machine but unable to get path on the cloud (Azure).
file saved exactly hierarchy like:

```
/src/main/resources/database/GeoLiteCity.dat
```

My Code:

```
void getFile() {
    if (this.file == null) {
        try {
            URL url =  this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("database/GeoLiteCity.dat");
            this.file = new File(url.toURI());
            System.out.println(file.getPath().toString());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(file.getPath().toString(),ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What Azure service did you use? Azure WebApps or Cloud Services?

Answer (score 0):

Assumption that the code is a part of Java WebApp running on Tomcat. Per my experience, if you want to get the resource via the method `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("<the data file path relative to the root classes path>")`, so please make sure the data file `GeoLiteCity.dat` under the path `webapps/<your-webapp-name>/WEB-INF/classes/database/`.

If your webapp was deployed on Azure WebApp, I think you can try to use the absolute path of data file on Azure WebApp, such as `D:/home/site/wwwroot/webapps/<your-webapp-name>/<the data file path>`, and only use `new File("<the absolute path of data file>")`.